# Adding home button to ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've just implemented ActionBarSherlock im my app, but it is not showing me HOME or BACK buttons. I see only the app name.So, anyone can tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```